# Python: explode column that contains dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, json-normalize

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

`df`:

```
amount    info
12        {id:'1231232', type:'trade', amount:12}
14        {id:'4124124', info:{operation_type:'deposit'}}
```

What I want to achieve is this:

`df`:

```
amount    type     operation_type
12        trade    Nan
14        Nan      deposit
```

I have tried the `df.explode('info')` method but with no luck. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do it in 2 steps: (i) Build a DataFrame `df` with `data`; (ii) use `json_normalize` on "info" column and `join` it back to `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
out = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['info'].tolist())[['type', 'info.operation_type']]).drop(columns='info')
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])
```

Output:

```
   amount   type operation_type
0      12  trade            NaN
1      14    NaN        deposit
```